# Gradient on AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have gradient in my AppBar so i added

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: GradientAppBar(
```

and

```
import 'package:gradient_app_bar/gradient_app_bar.dart';
```

and to my pubspec.yaml i added

```
dependencies:
  gradient_app_bar: ^0.0.1
```

But i still getting the following problem:

```
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorRenderObjectOfType'.
    return context.ancestorRenderObjectOfType(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can it fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to lastest version (0.1.3).